# testing for multiple bits being set

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, getopt

I am trying to configure a program through bit masks. What is the correct way to test for multiple bits being set or not set? Here is my attempt with explanatory comments:

```
#define GUI 0x01 // 2^0 
#define CLI 0x02 // 2^1 
#define CREATE 0x04 // 2^2 
#define VERIFY 0x08 // 2^3 
#define MULTIPLE 0x10 // 2^4 
#define FLAG32 0x20  // 2^5

unsigned char flags;

/* The application can have either CREATE or VERIFY true but not both. 
 * The application can run either on the CLI or the GUI but not both.
 * The defaults are have CLI and MULTIPLE set to true.
 * If CREATE is specified, then VERIFY is disabled, and vice-versa.
 * If FLAG32 is specified, then optarg is saved.
 */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

     // default without any flags
    flags = CLI | MULTIPLE; 

    int c;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "UCVR:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'U':
                flags |= GUI;
                flags &= ~CLI;
                break;
            case 'C':
                flags |= CREATE;
                flags &= ~VERIFY;
                flags &= ~MULTIPLE;
                break;
            case 'V':
                flags |= VERIFY;
                flags &= ~CREATE;
                flags &= ~MULTIPLE;
                break;
             case 'R':
                flags |= FLAG32;
                break;
        }        
    }
     
}
```

I tried testing for the presence of two bits like this and it seems to work:

```
if ((flags &  MULTIPLE ) && (flags & FLAG32))
    printf("MULTIPLE and FLAG32 is set\n");
```

Is there a briefer way using `<<` or something like that?

However, when I try the "obvious" for `NOT X` and `Y`, it doesn't seem to work:

```
if ( (flags &  MULTIPLE ) && (flags & ~FLAG32) )
    printf("MULTIPLE is set and FLAG32 is unset\n");
```

Do I have to care about which power of two a bit is at for this sort of thing?

Comment: `a & ~b` is not the same as `!(a & b)`.  Try some examples on paper.

Comment: "*Is there a briefer way*". Do you consider `(flags & (MULTIPLE | FLAG32))` to be briefer?

Comment: You can test for *both* of two bits with `(flags & (MULTIPLE | FLAG32)) == (MULTIPLE | FLAG32)` but I don't think it's any better than using `&&`.  Shift cannot help here.

Comment: I guess there's also de Morgan's law: `if ((~flags & (MULTIPLE | FLAG32)) == 0)` but that seems less comprehensible.

Comment: @NateEldredge Upvote for "less comprehensible".